# My recordset is ending my for each loop prematurely

Tags: sql, vb.net, for-loop, recordset

Okay, I have this code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Connection
    Dim rs1, tempSQL1
    Dim boxes

    Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Connection.Open(CONNECTION STRING HERE)

    tempSQL1 = "SELECT DISTINCT SOMETHING FROM SOMEWHERE"

    rs1.Open(tempSQL1, Connection)

    boxes = rs1.GetRows

    rs1 = Nothing

    Connection = Nothing

    For Each box As String In boxes

        With Me.CustomerSelect.Items
            .Add(pmbformat(box))
        End With

    Next



End Sub
```

Which works as expected, it adds 3 items to the drop down box CustomerSelect, one for each distinct entry in the recordset.

However, I want to add more information than just the box number to the item, so I change the for each loop to this

```
    For Each box As String In boxes

        With Me.CustomerSelect.Items
            .Add(pmbformat(box) & " " & rsQuery("LASTNAME", box) & ", " & rsQuery("FIRSTNAME", box))
        End With

    Next
```

Here is the function rsQuery

```
Function rsQuery(column As String, PMB As Integer)
    Dim Connection2, rs2, tempSQL2
    Dim myResult

    Connection2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    rs2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Connection2.Open(CONNECTION STRING HERE)

    tempSQL2 = "SELECT " & column & " FROM SOMEWHERE INNER JOIN SOMEWHERE-ELSE on SOMETHING=SOMETHING-ELSE WHERE SOMETHING-ELSE = " & PMB

    MsgBox(tempSQL2)

    rs2.Open(tempSQL2, Connection2)

    myResult = rs2(column).Value

    rs2 = Nothing

    Connection2 = Nothing

    Return myResult


End Function
```

This works once.  It adds one item (the first one) to the select box, with all the requested information.

The messagebox in function rsQuery was an attempt at debugging, it displays three times, once for the lastname of the first record, once for the firstname of the first record, and once for the lastname of the second record.  But it should display 6 times (first and last for 3 records).  Also since the msgbox does show up for the lastname of the 2nd record, you would think the Sub would add the item to the list, and omit the first name, but it doesnt.  The list remains with only the first option.

I have poured over this and Googled to no end and cannot find a fix.  Please help!

Thank you for looking at this, and in advance for your assistance.

P.S. Please forgive me for masking my sql statements and connection strings, but I am working for a 3rd party and they don't want that information public.  Based on the information I have given, it seems the connection strings and sql statements are correct.  I have also omitted the function pmbformat as this function works correctly.

Comment: if i have understood correctly ,your select distinct query gives your 3 records and are added successfully to combobox. Now you modified the loop to include more information in combobox. So you are expecting 6 records? But how can you get 6 records when your first select distinct query gives you only 3 records?

Comment: I am expecting 3 records, but only getting one.  I apologize if I was unclear, when I said that I expected 6 message boxes to appear I was referring to the fact that the rsQuery function is called twice for each record, therefore I should see the message box 6 times (3 records x 2 calls/record = 6)

Comment: Did you checked what you get value for myResult for all the 3 times?

Comment: Genious!  Apparently there was no customer record for the second PMB, so it was causing some kind of exception.  By adding 'If not rstemp.EOF' before 'myResult = rs2(column).Value' it bypasses the code that caused the exception.  Thanks!

Comment: Can i put it is answer and will you accept? Not sure if its good way

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was no customer record for the second PMB, so it was causing some kind of exception which stopped the processing. By adding

```
If not rstemp.EOF
```

before

```
myResult = rs2(column).Value
```

it bypasses the code that caused the exception.

It's always the simple things that get me.  :-)